# What is the name of this metal and wood handtool?

Tags: tools

I'm not sure what this tool is, could you please help identify it and what it might be used for?
[image: the screw fastens a blade in place, doesn't allow it to turn]

[image]

Comment: I remember my grandparents had one of these, they used it to cut stiff materials like thin cardboard etc.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a leather or even fabric cutter.

Seen similar a long time ago with a friend who was a saddler.

Comment: So not a pizza cutter?

Comment: @crip659 have to be thin crust but def not thick crust :)

Comment: Usually termed a "rotary cutter" these days; modern versions have replaceable blades.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an old wallpaper cutting tool. Or Rotary cutter as Chris states.
The blade wont hold a sharp enough edge for leather or cloth.
Here are some other examples[image]